# How can I parse in PHP to format user-submitted posts?

Tags: php, parsing, formatting

I want to give users some formatting options like Reddit or stackOverFlow do, but want to keep it in PHP. How can parse a string in PHP such that it recognizes patterns like `**[anything here]**`?

explode() doesn't seem to solve the problem as elegantly as I'd like. Should I just use nested ifs and fors based on explode()'s output? Is there a better solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been done countless times by others, I'd recommend using existing libraries.
For example, you can use Markdown: http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/

Comment: I saw markdown, and realize it's the best solution, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: [This blog](http://designelemental.net/blog/Markup-with-Markdown) covered how to use markdown within or without codeigniter.

Answer (score -1):

Check regular expressions:

```
$string = '*bold* or _underscored_ or even /italic/ ..';
// italic
$string = preg_replace('~/([^/]+)/~', '<i>$1</i>', $string);
// bold
$string = preg_replace('/\*([^\*]+)\*/', '<b>$1</b>', $string);
// underscore
$string = preg_replace('/_([^_]+)_/', '<u>$1</u>', $string);

echo $string;
```

output:

```
<b>bold</b> or <u>underscored</u> or even <i>italic</i> ..
```

or use a BBCode parser.